# calling azure graph api to fetch Get-PimAzureResourceRoleDefinition

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to a call graphapi to get roledefination but i am getting permission errors, and  have i checked my service prnciple it had all required permissions.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"errorCode\":\"PermissionScopeNotGranted\",\"message\":\"Authorization failed due to missing permission scope PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureResources,PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureResources.\",\"target\":null,\"details\":null,\"innerError\":null,\"instanceAnnotations\":[],\"typeAnnotation\":null}",
        "innerError": {
          "request-id": "d762f8d4-2cc4-428e-b1ea-7623d8d388f1",
          "date": "2020-06-03T04:25:03"
        }
      }
    }
    At line:38 char:15
    +     $Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $Headers
    +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand




    Below is my code
    ========================

    $TenantName = 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com'  
    $ClientId = 'xxxxxx'
    $ClientSecret = "xxxxxx"

    # Create a hashtable for the body, the data needed for the token request
    # The variables used are explained above
    $Body = @{
        'tenant' = $TenantId
        'client_id' = $ClientId
        'scope' = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
        'client_secret' = $ClientSecret
        'grant_type' = 'client_credentials'
    }

    $Params = @{
        'Uri' = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
        'Method' = 'Post'
        'Body' = $Body
        'ContentType' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    $AuthResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @Params

    $Headers = @{
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $($AuthResponse.access_token)"
    }

        #Find Pim Role
        $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedAccess/azureResources/resources/xxxxxxxxxxxx/roleDefinitions`?`$filter=displayName eq 'xxxxxx-Contributors'"

    $Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $Headers
```

Also how to get resource id of roledefination which we are passing in URL after /resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `Api permissions`, make sure the `PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureResources` is selected and click the button `Grant admin consent for xxx`.
[image]

You could decode your `access_token` via https://jwt.io/, `scp` shows your scopes.

**Update:**

> how to get resource id of roledefination which we are passing in URL after /resources

try request this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedAccess/azureResources/resources
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response my app had permissions mentioned above

Comment: @DevReddy Could you provide screenshots about `access_token`  in [https://jwt.io/](https://jwt.io/)?

Comment: @DevReddy Just the **scopes** in your `access_token`. You could update your issue and add it.

Comment: @DevReddy From the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/governanceroledefinition-get?view=graph-rest-beta#permissions),  this API requires the requestor to have at least one role assignment on the resource. You could try to navigate to **Subscription-> Access control (IAM)-> Add role assignment**, add your service principal as an `Owner`, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).